# Can shared object access memory of app that loaded it?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am new to shared libraries (Qt5/C++/Linux).  I managed to create an app which can load one of many .so files (one per animal: dog.so, cat.so, mouse.so).  So far works great.

I assumed that methods in the shared libraries could call methods in the app (eg: dog.so can call app::soundPlayerInstance() which gets a pointer to the SoundPlayer singleton in the app).

Although my code compiled fine, when I run the code it appears that the instance of SoundPlayer I'm getting is a NEW one.  (Another singleton created).

I suspect I am confused about what a .so can do.  Can an .so reach into the app that loaded it, to call methods, access global vars, etc?

If not, if the app passed object addresses into .so constructor, could it then?  Or is there a better way to do this?  Or is a shared object really a one way only (app call so) concept?

---

Update: My singleton template is below.  (Please don't get into debate about Singletons, just provided for reference)

```
// Create or return the instance if the derived class
static T* instance() {

    // If no instance yet, the create one
    s_mutex.lock();
    bool runPostConstructor = (s_instance == nullptr);
    if (s_instance == nullptr) s_instance = new T;
    s_mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: That's a matter of how the `SoundPlayer` singleton is implemented. I would suggest showing a [mre] and tagging this with `c++`.

Comment: I'm using a template I created for the singleton.  Since the s_instance is static I assumed it would use the same variable.  But if the .SO runs in a seperate memory space / seperate process then perhaps not.

Comment: "_Since the s_instance is static_": What do you mean exactly? Is `s_instance` a `static` class member or a namespace scope `static` variable? What about `instance`? Where exactly is the class template located? In an unnamed namespace or not? Are there any visibility attributes on the class or other entities? Are there any visibility flags to the compiler? All of that may affect the answer. In general the .so shares everything with the main application, given default visibility.

Comment: s_instance is a static class member defined in the template singleton class.  Not sure what you mean where is the class template located....but not in a namespace.  No visibility attributes (not even sure how I would do that).  Compiler is defaults (I'm not advanced enough to mess with them, so I can't be more specific yet).

Comment: Based on everything you said so far, there should be only once instance of `s_instance` in the whole program and it should be initialized with `new T` only once, regardless of shared libraries. There seems to be something wrong with your code somewhere that you haven't mentioned yet.

Comment: However, the function you are showing in your question has undefined behavior for missing a `return` statement. I assume that isn't actually in your code...

Comment: It's a snippet only.  This could turn into a very big question, I'm trying to keep it conceptual (not code specific)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if it knows the address of such objects. A shared library is not linked to the application. The application is linked to the library, so it knows how to locate functions. It is however very common to pass callback functions or objects from the application to the library. That way the library has an address, so it can call a function in the application.

Comment: So the .SO runs in the same memory space (if that's the right word) as the app that loaded it?

Comment: Yes, it runs in the same memory space.